# Run a basic command in Command Prompt using Apache spark with PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, command-prompt

I try to import data frame into spark using python pyspark. fro that I used jupter notebook and I write bellow code and i Got out put like below..
[image]

After that I want to run this in CMD fro that I save my python codes in text file and save as **test.py** (As python file) Then I Run that python file in cmd using **python test.py** command below the screen shot

[image]

So my task is completed but after 3 or 4 hours later I again try to do same process..Then unfortunately I got bellow error message can some one explain why its happens? because before  its correctly worked, but after that its not work and I not did any changes between these two attempt. below have full error now have facing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The way you're loading your CSV file requires that your test.py and te.csv need to be in the same folder, if they are in different folders you should pass the absolute path to the load function, eg : load ("C:/User/toto/te.csv")

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you have not set the Hadoop home (winutil.exe) in the command session which you have opened later.

The spark is unable to locate HADOOP_HOME. Check if you had set something different when you ran the command 1st time.

Comment: @ H Roy when save **test.py** and **te.csv** file in same location and run cmd then its work. I thing error in path settings. but are you think there have HADOOP_HOME error? but I already created these HADOOP_HOME in user and system variables section..